# Remove query string from 301 redirect URL

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble with redirects and I haven't been able to get this to work. I want to make the following

```
http://www.example.com/seasonal/christmas?p=15
```

redirect to

```
http://www.example.com/holiday-decor/christmas.html
```

I was wondering if someone could help me with the rewrite rule so the query string doesn't appear in the redirected URL. I'm using *.htaccess* with a Magento platform site.

Answer (score 6):

By default the query string on the requested URL is appended to the rewritten/redirected URL.

**On Apache 2.4+** you should use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive in order to *discard* the query string from the redirected URL. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =p=15
RewriteRule ^seasonal/christmas$ /holiday-decor/christmas.html [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive is required in order to match the query string part of the requested URL. (The URL matched by the `RewriteRule` pattern is the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string.) The `=` prefix on the *CondPattern* `=p=15` indicates a literal "string" match (as opposed to a regex), so it matches `p=15` exactly.

**On Apache 2.2 and earlier** you would instead need to append a `?` at the end of the `RewriteRule` substitution, to remove the query string. This essentially writes a *blank* query string (the `?` does not actually become part of the redirected URL). Note that by appending any query string on the *substitution string* you overwrite the query string on the request. (If you needed to also append the original query string in this situation then you need the `QSA` flag - Query String Append - but otherwise, this flag is not required.)

For example, on Apache 2.2, you would change the above `RewriteRule` directive to read:

```
RewriteRule ^seasonal/christmas$ /holiday-decor/christmas.html? [R=301,L]
```

NB: Appending the `?` also works on Apache 2.4. Although using the `QSD` flag is preferred. The two methods are not identical.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding this to your *.htaccess* in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?start=0(.*)$  
RewriteRule ^/?products\.php$ /products.php?%1%2 [R=301,NE]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question or even work with the OPs example?! This particular example is intended to remove a particular segment (name/value pair) from a query string, whilst maintaining the rest of it.