# 301 Redirect from URL with query string to new URL without query string

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, query-string, mod-alias

I'm having trouble working out how to do a 301 redirect from:

`https://www.example.com/catalogue/catalogue.php?catSection=1`

to

`https://www.example.com/hire-category/access-support-equipment/`

I've tried a few things including from this thread: [Remove query string from 301 redirect URL](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56348/remove-query-string-from-301-redirect-url)

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =catSection=1
RewriteRule ^catalogue/catalogue.php$ /hire-category/access-support-equipment/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

But that isn't working for me.

---

Full .htaccess as it stands at the moment:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
# Top Level Pages
redirect 301 /about.php     https://www.example.com/about/
redirect 301 /quality.php   https://www.example.com/quality-of-service/
redirect 301 /history.php   https://www.example.com/history-of-didcot-plant/
redirect 301 /sales.php     https://www.example.com/
redirect 301 /health-safety.php https://www.example.com/health-safety/
redirect 301 /hav.php   https://www.example.com/hand-arm-vibration-in-the-workplace/
redirect 301 /hav-equipment.php https://www.example.com/hand-arm-vibration-emission-values/
redirect 301 /contact.php   https://www.example.com/contact/
redirect 301 /accountapplication/   https://www.example.com/account-application/
redirect 301 /accountapplication/credit-account.php https://www.example.com/apply-for-credit-account/
redirect 301 /accountapplication/cash-account.php   https://www.example.com/apply-cash-account/
redirect 301 /covid-operatingconditions.php     https://www.example.com/covid-19-operating-conditions/
redirect 301 /terms.php https://www.example.com/terms-conditions/
redirect 301 /privacy.php   https://www.example.com/privacy/
redirect 301 /sitemap.php   https://www.example.com/
redirect 301 /directions.php    https://www.example.com/directions/
redirect 301 /testimonials.php  https://www.example.com/testimonials/

# Catalogue
redirect 301 /catalogue/    https://www.example.com/hire-catalogue/?

# News
redirect 301 /news/2021/04/extra-hydraulic-rotavators-arrive/   https://www.example.com/extra-hydraulic-rotavators-arrive/
redirect 301 /news/2021/04/new-stump-grinder/   https://www.example.com/new-stump-grinder/
redirect 301 /news/2021/03/new-dumpers-added-to-fleet/  https://www.example.com/new-dumpers-added-to-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2021/02/another-turf-cutter-added-to-fleet/  https://www.example.com/another-turf-cutter-added-to-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2021/01/spring-preparations-begin/   https://www.example.com/spring-preparations-begin/
redirect 301 /news/2020/11/new-stihl-disc-cutters/  https://www.example.com/new-stihl-disc-cutters/
redirect 301 /news/2020/11/new-mini-dumper/ https://www.example.com/new-mini-dumper/
redirect 301 /news/2020/11/new-heaters-arrive/  https://www.example.com/new-heaters-arrive/
redirect 301 /news/2020/10/new-paslode-nailers-added-to-fleet/  https://www.example.com/new-paslode-nailers-added-to-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2020/09/extra-milwaukee-900k-breakers-purchased/ https://www.example.com/extra-milwaukee-900k-breakers-purchased/
redirect 301 /news/2020/06/changing-excavator-buckets/  https://www.example.com/changing-excavator-buckets/
redirect 301 /news/2020/06/how-to-start-a-honda-engine/ https://www.example.com/how-to-start-a-honda-engine/
redirect 301 /news/2020/06/how-to-build-a-concrete-base-for-a-garden-shed/  https://www.example.com/how-to-build-a-concrete-base-for-a-garden-shed/
redirect 301 /news/2020/05/new-k008-added-to-fleet/ https://www.example.com/new-k008-added-to-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2020/02/new-kubota-3-0t-digger/  https://www.example.com/new-3-0t-digger/
redirect 301 /news/2020/01/stihl-ts410-disc-cutters/    https://www.example.com/stihl-ts410-disc-cutters/
redirect 301 /news/2019/11/new-kubota-model-joins-fleet/    https://www.example.com/new-kubota-model-joins-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2019/08/further-investment-new-floor-sanders/    https://www.example.com/further-investment-new-floor-sanders/
redirect 301 /news/2019/07/new-kubota-kx057-4-joins-hire-fleet/ https://www.example.com/new-kubota-kx057-4-joins-hire-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2019/05/new-lorry-on-the-road/   https://www.example.com/new-lorry-on-the-road/
redirect 301 /news/2019/04/trio-of-genies/  https://www.example.com/trio-of-genies/
redirect 301 /news/2019/03/three-new-hinowa-mini-dumpers/   https://www.example.com/three-new-hinowa-mini-dumpers/
redirect 301 /news/2019/03/green-seat-belt-beacons-fully-available/ https://www.example.com/green-seat-belt-beacons-fully-available/
redirect 301 /news/2019/02/two-manitou-telehandlers-arrive/ https://www.example.com/two-manitou-telehandlers-arrive/
redirect 301 /news/2019/02/new-kubota-3t-excavators/    https://www.example.com/new-kubota-3t-excavators/
redirect 301 /news/2019/01/new-bomag-120ad-5-arrives/   https://www.example.com/new-bomag-120ad-5-arrives/
redirect 301 /news/2019/01/petrol-pump-fleet-overhauled/    https://www.example.com/petrol-pump-fleet-overhauled/
redirect 301 /news/2018/12/new-portable-masonry-saws/   https://www.example.com/new-portable-masonry-saws/
redirect 301 /news/2018/06/big-investment-in-hire-fleet-in-2018/    https://www.example.com/big-investment-in-hire-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2018/01/kubotas-new-kx030-4-excavator-arrives/   https://www.example.com/kubotas-new-kx030-4-excavator-arrives/
redirect 301 /news/2018/01/re-handling-bucket-telehandler/  https://www.example.com/re-handling-bucket-for-telehandler/
redirect 301 /news/2017/11/indirect-heaters-join-range/ https://www.example.com/indirect-heaters-join-our-range/
redirect 301 /news/2017/09/volvo-excavators-double-addition/    https://www.example.com/volvo-excavators-double-addition/
redirect 301 /news/2017/08/two-new-6t-dumpers/  https://www.example.com/two-new-6t-dumpers/
redirect 301 /news/2017/08/telehandlers-at-the-double/  https://www.example.com/telehandlers-at-the-double/
redirect 301 /news/2017/07/new-hi-tip-barrow/   https://www.example.com/new-hi-tip-barrow/
redirect 301 /news/2017/07/two-more-diggers/    https://www.example.com/two-more-diggers/
redirect 301 /news/2017/05/new-bomag-120ad-5-roller/    https://www.example.com/new-bomag-120ad-5-roller/
redirect 301 /news/2017/04/peckers-pack-punch/  https://www.example.com/these-peckers-pack-a-punch/
redirect 301 /news/2017/02/new-swivel-dumpers-purchased/    https://www.example.com/new-swivel-dumpers-purchased/
redirect 301 /news/2016/12/telehandlers-added-range/    https://www.example.com/telehandlers-added-to-range/
redirect 301 /news/2016/11/winter-christmas-opening-times-20162017/ https://www.example.com/winter-and-christmas-opening-times-2016-2017/
redirect 301 /news/2016/10/new-bomag-roller/    https://www.example.com/new-bomag-roller/
redirect 301 /news/2016/10/another-kx015-4/ https://www.example.com/another-kx015-4/
redirect 301 /news/2016/10/new-hilux-van/   https://www.example.com/new-hilux-van/
redirect 301 /news/2016/09/new-plant-trailer-2/ https://www.example.com/new-plant-trailer/
redirect 301 /news/2016/09/new-hi-tip-dumper/   https://www.example.com/new-hi-tip-dumper/
redirect 301 /news/2016/07/trio-of-dumpers/ https://www.example.com/trio-of-dumpers/
redirect 301 /news/2015/09/new-jcb-beaver-iii-powerpacks/   https://www.example.com/new-jcb-beaver-iii-powerpacks/
redirect 301 /news/2015/09/two-new-kubotas-arrive/  https://www.example.com/two-new-kubotas-arrive/
redirect 301 /news/2015/02/nine-new-kubotas/    https://www.example.com/nine-new-kubotas/
redirect 301 /news/2014/09/two-new-volvo-9-tonne-diggers-added-fleet/   https://www.example.com/two-new-volvo-9tonne-diggers-added-to-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2014/09/new-6-tonne-dumper-purchased/    https://www.example.com/new-6tonne-dumper-purchased/
redirect 301 /news/2014/05/new-plant-trailer/   https://www.example.com/new-plant-trailer-2/
redirect 301 /news/2014/04/5-tonne-digger-fleet-grows/  https://www.example.com/5tonne-digger-fleet-grows/
redirect 301 /news/2014/03/new-stump-grinder-purchased/ https://www.example.com/new-stump-grinder-purchased/
redirect 301 /news/2013/07/mobile-website-launched/ https://www.example.com/mobile-website-launched/
redirect 301 /news/2013/07/new-roller/  https://www.example.com/new-roller/
redirect 301 /news/2013/05/new-digger-and-dumper-join-fleet/    https://www.example.com/new-digger-and-dumper-join-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2012/12/5-tonne-excavator-fleet-increased/   https://www.example.com/5-tonne-excavator-fleet-increased/
redirect 301 /news/2012/11/new-skip-loading-power-barrows/  https://www.example.com/new-skip-loading-power-barrows/
redirect 301 /news/2012/07/new-weldergenerator/ https://www.example.com/new-welder-generator/
redirect 301 /news/2012/07/new-compound-saw-a-cut-above/    https://www.example.com/new-compound-saw-a-cut-above/
redirect 301 /news/2012/07/two-new-hot-cold-pressure-washers/   https://www.example.com/two-new-hot-cold-pressure-washers/
redirect 301 /news/2012/04/new-box-van-trailer/ https://www.example.com/new-box-van-trailer/
redirect 301 /news/2012/04/new-swivel-dumpers-join-our-range/   https://www.example.com/new-swivel-dumpers-join-our-range/
redirect 301 /news/2012/03/new-8-tonne-volvo-added-to-fleet/    https://www.example.com/new-8-tonne-volvo-added-to-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2012/03/new-tillers-ready-for-spring/    https://www.example.com/new-honda-tillers/
redirect 301 /news/2012/03/ready-for-a-flood-of-hires/  https://www.example.com/ready-for-a-flood-of-hires/
redirect 301 /news/2012/03/new-bomag-80ad-5-roller/ https://www.example.com/new-bomag-80ad-5-roller/
redirect 301 /news/2012/01/compressor-order-completed/  https://www.example.com/compressor-order-completed/
redirect 301 /news/2012/01/new-3-tonne-excavator-added/ https://www.example.com/new-3-tonne-excavator-added/
redirect 301 /news/2011/11/new-compressor-arrives/  https://www.example.com/new-compressor-arrives/
redirect 301 /news/2011/11/new-generators-arrive/   https://www.example.com/new-generators-arrive/
redirect 301 /news/2011/11/another-new-k008-excavator-arrives/  https://www.example.com/another-new-k008-excavator-arrives/
redirect 301 /news/2011/05/new-kubota-k008-digger-arrives/  https://www.example.com/new-kubota-k008-excavator-arrives/
redirect 301 /news/2011/04/new-9hp-rotavator/   https://www.example.com/new-9hp-rotavator/
redirect 301 /news/2011/04/two-new-thwaites-1-tonne-hi-tips/    https://www.example.com/new-thwaites-hi-tip-dumpers/
redirect 301 /news/2011/03/new-fencing/ https://www.example.com/new-fencing/
redirect 301 /news/2011/03/new-turf-cutters/    https://www.example.com/new-turf-cutters/
redirect 301 /news/2011/03/new-3-tonne-excavator-arrives/   https://www.example.com/new-3-tonne-excavator-arrives/
redirect 301 /news/2011/01/central-heating-power-flusher-joins-our-range/   https://www.example.com/central-heating-power-flusher-joins-our-range/
redirect 301 /news/2010/11/extra-fein-multimaster-added/    https://www.example.com/extra-fein-multimaster-added/
redirect 301 /news/2010/11/new-scarifier-joins-our-range/   https://www.example.com/new-scarifier-joins-our-range/
redirect 301 /news/2010/10/new-tile-stripper/   https://www.example.com/new-tile-stripper/
redirect 301 /news/2010/09/disc-cutter-fleet-now-100-stihl/ https://www.example.com/disc-cutter-fleet-now-100-stihl/
redirect 301 /news/2010/05/two-new-3-tonne-dumpers-arrive/  https://www.example.com/two-new-3-tonne-dumpers-arrive/
redirect 301 /news/2010/04/hire-deal-of-the-month-may-2010/ https://www.example.com/hire-deal-of-the-month-may-2010/
redirect 301 /news/2010/04/four-new-2-tonne-dumpers-arrive/ https://www.example.com/four-new-2-tonne-dumpers-arrive/
redirect 301 /news/2010/03/hire-deal-of-the-month-march-2010/   https://www.example.com/hire-deal-of-the-month-march-2010/
redirect 301 /news/2010/01/hire-deal-of-the-month-february-2010/    https://www.example.com/hire-deal-of-the-month-february-2010/
redirect 301 /news/2009/12/roller-strikers-join-our-range/  https://www.example.com/roller-strikers-join-our-range/
redirect 301 /news/2009/11/new-website-launched/    https://www.example.com/new-website-launched/
redirect 301 /news/2009/10/featured-equipment-thwaites-1-tonne-hi-tip-dumper/   https://www.example.com/featured-equipment-thwaites-1-tonne-hi-tip-dumper/
redirect 301 /news/2009/10/how-to-sand-a-floor/ https://www.example.com/how-to-sand-a-floor/
redirect 301 /news/2009/10/combating-flood-damage/  https://www.example.com/combating-flood-damage/
redirect 301 /news/2009/10/featured-equipment-temporary-fencing/    https://www.example.com/featured-equipment-temporary-fencing/
redirect 301 /news/2009/10/featured-equipment-volvo-ec55-excavator/ https://www.example.com/featured-equipment-volvo-ec55-excavator/
redirect 301 /news/2009/10/featured-equipment-volvo-8-tonne-excavator/  https://www.example.com/featured-equipment-volvo-8-tonne-excavator/
redirect 301 /news/2009/10/featured-equipment-skip-loading-power-barrows/   https://www.example.com/featured-equipment-skip-loading-power-barrows/
redirect 301 /news/2009/10/featured-equipment-rotavators/   https://www.example.com/featured-equipment-rotavators/
redirect 301 /news/2009/10/featured-equipment-kubota-k008-excavator/    https://www.example.com/featured-equipment-kubota-k008-excavator/
redirect 301 /news/2009/10/featured-equipment-floor-sanders/    https://www.example.com/featured-equipment-floor-sanders/
redirect 301 /news/2009/04/three-wishes-from-genie/ https://www.example.com/three-wishes-from-genie/
redirect 301 /news/2009/04/triple-bill-of-new-rollers-arrive/   https://www.example.com/triple-bill-of-new-rollers-arrive/
redirect 301 /news/2009/04/trio-of-kx36s-join-digger-fleet/ https://www.example.com/trio-of-kx36s-join-digger-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2009/03/two-new-stihl-pressure-washers-added/    https://www.example.com/two-new-stihl-pressure-washers-added/
redirect 301 /news/2009/03/two-new-5-tonne-volvos-arrive/   https://www.example.com/two-new-5-tonne-volvos-arrive/
redirect 301 /news/2009/03/new-laser-level-added/   https://www.example.com/new-laser-level-added/
redirect 301 /news/2009/02/didcot-plant-focus-issue-6/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-focus-issue-6/
redirect 301 /news/2008/12/reversible-plates-return/    https://www.example.com/reversible-plates-return/
redirect 301 /news/2008/10/bomag-rollers-get-some-tlc/  https://www.example.com/bomag-rollers-get-some-tlc/
redirect 301 /news/2008/10/2nd-genie-lift-added-to-hire-fleet/  https://www.example.com/2ns-genie-lift-added-to-hire-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2008/07/long-reach-hedge-trimmer-joins-range/    https://www.example.com/long-reach-hedge-trimmer-joins-range/
redirect 301 /news/2008/07/your-wish-is-our-command/    https://www.example.com/your-wish-is-our-command/
redirect 301 /news/2008/07/new-gardening-equipment-added/   https://www.example.com/new-gardening-equipment-added/
redirect 301 /news/2008/06/stump-grinder-added-to-range/    https://www.example.com/stump-grinder-added-to-range/
redirect 301 /news/2008/06/rammer-fleet-increased/  https://www.example.com/rammer-fleet-increased/
redirect 301 /news/2008/06/new-air-conditioners-join-hire-fleet/    https://www.example.com/new-air-conditioners-join-hire-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2008/05/didcot-plant-focus-issue-3/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-focus-issue-3/
redirect 301 /news/2008/04/bumpa-hoist-added-to-range/  https://www.example.com/bumpa-hoist-added-to-range/
redirect 301 /news/2008/03/new-kubota-kx71-joins-hire-fleet/    https://www.example.com/new-kubota-kx71-joins-hire-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2008/03/didcot-plant-focus-issue-2/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-focus-issue-2/
redirect 301 /news/2008/02/two-new-kubota-kx36s-arrive/ https://www.example.com/two-new-kubota-kx36s-arrive/
redirect 301 /news/2008/01/new-volvo-5t-breaker/    https://www.example.com/new-volvo-5t-breaker/
redirect 301 /news/2008/01/a-busy-year/ https://www.example.com/a-busy-year/
redirect 301 /news/2008/01/99-vat-cordless-drill/   https://www.example.com/99-vat-makita-cordless-drill/
redirect 301 /news/2008/01/website-continues-to-be-upgraded/    https://www.example.com/website-continues-to-be-upgraded/
redirect 301 /news/2008/01/new-vehicles-grace-our-fleet/    https://www.example.com/new-vehicles-grace-our-fleet/
redirect 301 /news/2008/01/80-tonner-free-again/    https://www.example.com/8-0-tonner-free-again/
redirect 301 /news/2008/01/new-dehumidifiers/   https://www.example.com/new-dehumidifiers/
redirect 301 /news/2008/01/didcot-plant-focus-issue-1/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-focus-issue-1/
redirect 301 /news/2007/12/didcot-plant-news-december-2007/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-december-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2007/11/didcot-plant-news-november-2007/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-november-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2007/10/didcot-plant-news-october-2007/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-october-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2007/09/didcot-plant-news-september-2007/    https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-september-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2007/08/didcot-plant-news-august-2007/   https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-august-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2007/07/didcot-plant-news-july-2007/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-july-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2007/06/didcot-plant-news-june-2007/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-june-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2007/05/didcot-plant-news-may-2007/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-may-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2007/04/didcot-plant-news-april-2007/    https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-april-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2007/03/didcot-plant-news-march-2007/    https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-march-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2007/02/didcot-plant-news-february-2007/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-february-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2007/01/didcot-plant-news-january-2007/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-january-2007/
redirect 301 /news/2006/12/didcot-plant-news-december-2006/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-december-2006/
redirect 301 /news/2006/11/didcot-plant-news-november-2006/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-november-2006/
redirect 301 /news/2006/08/didcot-plant-news-august-2006/   https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-august-2006/
redirect 301 /news/2006/06/didcot-plant-news-june-2006/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-june-2006/
redirect 301 /news/2006/02/didcot-plant-news-february-2006/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-february-2006/
redirect 301 /news/2005/12/didcot-plant-news-december-2005/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-december-2005/
redirect 301 /news/2005/08/didcot-plant-news-august-2005/   https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-august-2005/
redirect 301 /news/2005/07/didcot-plant-news-july-2005/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-july-2005/
redirect 301 /news/2005/05/didcot-plant-news-may-2005/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-may-2005/
redirect 301 /news/2005/04/didcot-plant-news-april-2005/    https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-april-2005/
redirect 301 /news/2005/03/didcot-plant-news-march-2005/    https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-march-2005/
redirect 301 /news/2005/02/didcot-plant-news-february-2005/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-february-2005/
redirect 301 /news/2004/12/didcot-plant-news-december-2004/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-december-2004/
redirect 301 /news/2004/11/didcot-plant-news-november-2004/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-november-2004/
redirect 301 /news/2004/09/didcot-plant-news-september-2004/    https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-september-2004/
redirect 301 /news/2004/08/didcot-plant-news-august-2004/   https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-august-2004/
redirect 301 /news/2004/07/didcot-plant-news-july-2004/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-july-2004/
redirect 301 /news/2004/06/didcot-plant-news-june-2004/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-june-2004/
redirect 301 /news/2004/05/didcot-plant-news-may-2004/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-may-2004/
redirect 301 /news/2004/04/didcot-plant-news-april-2004/    https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-april-2004/
redirect 301 /news/2004/03/didcot-plant-news-march-2004/    https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-march-2004/
redirect 301 /news/2004/02/didcot-plant-news-february-2004/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-february-2004/
redirect 301 /news/2004/01/didcot-plant-news-january-2004/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-january-2004/
redirect 301 /news/2003/11/didcot-plant-news-november-2003/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-november-2003/
redirect 301 /news/2003/08/didcot-plant-news-august-2003/   https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-august-2003/
redirect 301 /news/2003/07/didcot-plant-news-july-2003/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-july-2003/
redirect 301 /news/2003/05/didcot-plant-news-may-2003/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-may-2003/
redirect 301 /news/2002/12/didcot-plant-news-december-2002/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-december-2002/
redirect 301 /news/2002/10/didcot-plant-news-october-2002/  https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-october-2002/
redirect 301 /news/2002/09/didcot-plant-news-september-2002/    https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-september-2002/
redirect 301 /news/2002/06/didcot-plant-news-june-2002/ https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-june-2002/
redirect 301 /news/2002/04/didcot-plant-news-april-2002/    https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-april-2002/
redirect 301 /news/2002/03/didcot-plant-news-march-2002/    https://www.example.com/didcot-plant-news-march-2002/
redirect 301 /news/category/news/   https://www.example.com/category/news/
redirect 301 /news/category/featured-equipment/ https://www.example.com/category/featured-equipment/
redirect 301 /news/category/articles/   https://www.example.com/category/news/
redirect 301 /news/2021 https://www.example.com/2021/
redirect 301 /news/2020 https://www.example.com/2020/
redirect 301 /news/2019 https://www.example.com/2019/
redirect 301 /news/2018/    https://www.example.com/2018/
redirect 301 /news/2017/    https://www.example.com/2017/
redirect 301 /news/2016/    https://www.example.com/2016/
redirect 301 /news/2015/    https://www.example.com/2015/
redirect 301 /news/2014/    https://www.example.com/2014/
redirect 301 /news/2013/    https://www.example.com/2013/
redirect 301 /news/2012/    https://www.example.com/2012/
redirect 301 /news/2011/    https://www.example.com/2011/
redirect 301 /news/2010/    https://www.example.com/2010/
redirect 301 /news/2009/    https://www.example.com/2009/
redirect 301 /news/2008/    https://www.example.com/2008/
redirect 301 /news/2007/    https://www.example.com/2007/
redirect 301 /news/2006/    https://www.example.com/2006/
redirect 301 /news/2005/    https://www.example.com/2005/
redirect 301 /news/2004/    https://www.example.com/2004/
redirect 301 /news/2003/    https://www.example.com/2003/
redirect 301 /news/2002/    https://www.example.com/2002/
```

Comment: Do you have other `RewriteRule`s?  For example is there a rule to rewrite `/hire-category/access-support-equipment/` to some PHP script?

Comment: "But that isn't working for me" - In what way is it not working exactly? Do you get an error? Undesirable redirect? Nothing?! Where are you using this directive? The directive you posted assumes you are using `.htaccess` on Apache 2.4, in which case it would appear to do precisely what you are asking.

Comment: Do you have a `RewriteEngine On` directive? (Need to ask, as it's not explicitly included in the question you've referenced.)

Comment: Thanks all for your questions.

Comment: I have got RewriteEngine On and have a bunch of redirects in place for the top level pages. Here's an example of one of them:
redirect 301 /about.php https://www.example.com/about/

Comment: These simple redirects are working fine, and it's when I start dealing with the more complex URLs that I'm stumbling.

Comment: If I include the rule that I've given as an example in my post above, it doesn't do anything - the URL in the address bar is the original and I get an 404 as the page no longer exists.

Comment: I haven't got any rules rewriting to PHP scripts.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your entire `.htaccess`(?) file. You should avoid mixing redirects using both `Redirect` and `RewriteRule` directives as this can potentially cause conflicts. To clarify, if you were to request `/hire-category/access-support-equipment/` directly does it work? (Is that a physical directory?)

Comment: Also, what type of hosting are you using? Do you have your own server? Or is this "shared hosting"?

Comment: Thanks MrWhite, I really appreciate your help. I'm on shared hosting.

Comment: I think I've found a workaround for the hire catalogue section of the site using this: redirect 301 /catalogue/ https://www.example.com/hire-catalogue/?

Comment: It means that any of the previous URLs with query strings are sent to the main hire catalogue page instead of a 404 - which is a step in the right direction. And means I don't need to individually match up the many URLs. Not perfect, I know but I think it will do. And Google is already listing the new URLs :-)

Comment: Although that `Redirect` directive does something quite different to what you are trying to do in the question and completely ignores the query string? It would redirect `/catalogue/catalogue.php?catSection=1` to `/hire-catalogue/catalogue.php?catSection=1`. If you edit your question to include the contents of your `.htaccess` file this should be relatively trivial to resolve. (There is an "edit" link immediately below the question.) Also, do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path?

Comment: Thanks MrWhite, I really am grateful that you want to help. And I know that what I've done is a compromise but I am glad at least that people aren't being directed to a 404 page.

Comment: I will post my .htaccess above. The new site is a WordPress site.

Answer (score 1):

You've not actually shown the new directives (mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` / `RewriteCond`) in-place in your `.htaccess` file, but my guess is that you were putting the directives in the wrong place. Order matters. If you place the mod_rewrite directives together with your mod_alias `Redirect` directives, *after* the WordPress front-controller (`# BEGIN WordPress` section) then it's not going to do anything because `/catalogue/catalogue.php` (which does not exist) is rewritten to `/index.php` before your redirect occurs at which time processing stops and the redirect never occurs, resulting in a 404 from WordPress.

**You need to place the new redirect, ie. the mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` (and `RewriteCond`) directives *before* the existing mod_rewrite directives, ie. *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section, near the top of your `.htaccess` file.**

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the existing 301 (*permanent*) redirect will have been cached by the browser. For this reason it is beneficial to first test with 302 (temporary) redirects which are not cached by default.

The mod_alias `Redirect` directives are OK where they are, later in the file, *after* the WordPress front-controller, because they belong to a different Apache module and always work on the initial request (not the rewritten request).

`RewriteEngine`, `RewriteRule` (and `RewriteCond`) directives are part of mod_rewrite. However, `Redirect` is a mod_alias directive. Different Apache modules work independently and are processed at different times during the request, despite the apparent order of directives in the config file. mod_rewrite always runs before mod_alias. For this reason, it is generally advisable to not mix redirects from both modules, since you can get unexpected conflicts.

Consequently, the `RewriteEngine` directive has nothing to do with the mod_alias `Redirect` directive. Although where you've placed the `RewriteEngine` directive would seem to suggest you think there is? There's also no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive. Only the *last* instance of the `RewriteEngine` directive actually does anything and controls the entire file.

---

*Aside:* From comments...

> is there a rule to rewrite /hire-category/access-support-equipment/ to some PHP script?
>
> I haven't got any rules rewriting to PHP scripts.

This is precisely what the existing WordPress directives do (the part in the `# BEGIN WordPress` section). It internally rewrites `/hire-category/access-support-equipment/` to `/index.php` (the WordPress front-controller).